# C# COM server access from JScript

Tags: c#, com-interop, javascript

I have a COM server, implemented in C#. It exposes a class decorated like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("MyServer.MyClass")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
```

I registered the DLL with "regasm /codebase MyServer". This server must be used from a WSC (a COM server implemented in JScript). Therefore I used the AutoDispatch interface.

When the WSC calls

```
o = new ActiveXObject("MyServer.MyClass");
```

I get the error "Automation serve can't create object".

I checked the registration of the COM server with this C++ program:

```
hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = ::CLSIDFromProgID(L"MyServer.MyClass", &clsid);
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IDispatch, (void**)&pObj);
```

and was able to create the object. All return values have been checked to be S_OK.

What is needed to make the COM server accessible for JScript?

Comment: The JScript code can create the instance of the ActiveXObject on Windows XP (32 bit). But the same code fails on Windows 7 (64 bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is x64, see the answer of [Hot to make COM ActiveX object work in IE 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736424/hot-to-make-com-activex-object-work-in-ie-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Are the types used in your class [ole automation compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367129%28VS.85%29.aspx)? I don't know if jscript checks for oleautomation compatibility up front.